# How do I reference a repeater (or other object) from a public function?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, repeater, global

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 (VB) application with a bunch of repeaters spread throughout several pages and user controls. I am trying to create a single public function that I can call to databind and paginate whichever repeater I specify, but am having difficulties referencing the repeater object from within that public function so that the function will know which repeater , on which page, is calling it. Is there a way to do this or is my underlying method flawed?

Comment: You haven't given us a lot to work with. Where is your public function? Is it a static method on a class, or is it in global.asax, or ...?

Comment: It is a public sub in a self-contained .VB module where I keep what I guess you would call my "global" functions and subs.  I would be calling this sub from the code behind in a user control. I use this module for other purposes without any issue but this is the first case where I am needing to perform changes to actual objects inside the actual page(s) that are calling it.

Comment: Pass in the repeater (ByRef) as a parameter and use the ID property.

Comment: Thanks NoAlias. I do not need to pass in the calling page also?

Comment: Is is always a different repeater or the same repeater? Also, is your repeater binding on the code behind?

Comment: NoAlias's answer will certainly work, but you might consider creating a base class for your user control to inherit from as a more flexible way of re-using functionality, with Overridable methods so you can either use the default function or do something specific to one particular repeater. Using a base control will neatly encapsulate the repeater, and make the issue of addressing the local instance straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in any control you need to manipulate ByRef as a parameter into your function (ex = Page, Repeater, etc).  If you're performing different logic for each repeater/page it seems silly to make an all encompassing function to handle it.  If most repeaters follow the same code path in your function or something in your function must be called on all of those repeaters, then it makes sense to follow this model.

Comment: byref makes no difference in this case, may as well be byval.